# How to find people who likes each other?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql. There is likes_table for users. However, I am stuck to find people who like each other.

likes_table:

```
id (unique), from_user_id, to_user_id
1,3,1
2,1,3
3,1,64
4,1,2
5,2,1
```

For example, I want to find mutual likes for from_user_id =1 
Therefore expected result should be:

```
2,3
```

I tried to connect two columns with IN command.

SQL code I tried:

```
Select to_user_id from likes_table where from_user_id IN (Select from_user_id from likes_table where to_user_id = #id)
```

This gives only user_id=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to filter the table for two conditions:

- Row where the `from_user_id = 1`; and,
- The reciprocal row exists.

The second condition can be handled using `exists`:

```
select l.to_user_id
from likes l
where l.from_user_id = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from likes l2
              where l2.from_user_id = l.to_user_id and 
                    l2.to_user_id = l.from_user_id
             )
```

Comment: The last where condition should be AND, right? the , causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

you were almost there, what you want is actually the from_id :

```
Select from_user_id from likes_table where from_user_id IN (Select from_user_id from likes_table where to_user_id = #id)
```

Comment: Thanks but result has duplicated values. For example, 
Select fromU from friends where fromU IN (Select fromU  from friends where toU = "3") 
gives 1,1,1

Comment: that's correct, you could just add a Distinct statement
Select DISTINCT fromU from friends where fromU IN (Select fromU  from friends where toU = "3")
Would that work?

Comment: By the way my query was wrong again, I was missing a where clause. This one works https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7s1yso9B181jVVbfjyCj9/2 
Select DISTINCT 
toU from friends 
where toU IN (Select fromU  from friends where toU = "1") AND  fromU = "1"